# Get all the items inside SharePoint list which have their Ids inside a collection without raising any delegation errors

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I have 2 SharePoint lists:-

1. Parent_1.
2. Child2 . has a ParentId field which store the Parent_1 id in a single line of text.

Now i want to do these 2 operations:-

1. Build a collection which contain all the Parentid from the Child2 list.
2. set the Items property of a ComboBox to only contain the Parent_1 records which have an Id inside the collection. In other words the ComboBox should only contain Parent_1 records which are assigned to at-least one Child2 record.

Now i tried this **Appraoch-1**

Inside the Screen Onvisible, i built the following collection:-

```
ClearCollect(childcol,ShowColumns(Child2,"ParentId"));
```

and inside the Item property i tired the following, but i got a delegation warning on the "in" operator:-

```
Filter(Parent_1, ID in childcol.ParentId).Title
```

Then i tried **Appraoch-2**, where inside the screen OnVisible, i build the following 2 collections:-

```
ClearCollect(childcol,Child2, ["ParentId"]);
ForAll(childcol,Collect(parentcol,Filter(Parent_1,ID=childcol[@ID])));
```

then inside the Items property of the Combobox, i define the following:-

```
parentcol.Title
```

I did not get any delegation warning but the ComboBox will be empty.

any advice how i can Get all the items inside SharePoint list which have their Ids inside a collection without raising any delegation errors

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this -

```
ClearCollect(
    colChildDropDown,
    ForAll(
        Parent_1 As _items,
        If(
            !IsBlank(
                LookUp(
                    Child2,
                    ParentId = _items.ID
                ).ParentId
            ),
            {
                ID: _items.ID,
                Value: _items.Title
            }
        )
    )
)
```